# Notes played on internal PC speaker off key

Tags: assembly, audio, x86, x86-16

I've been writing a simple bootsector program to play notes with the internal PC speaker when
the user presses keys.`I've calculated the numbers I should give to the PC speaker by dividing 1193180 by the frequency of the note I want to play. The problem is, the notes sound very off-key. I've tried tweaking the numbers, and the sound that the PC speaker plays doesn't change at all.

Here is the code:

```
input:         ; takes user input and sets ax based on the key pressed
    mov ah, 00h
    int 16h
    cmp al, 'a'
    je seta
    cmp al, 's'
    je sets
    cmp al, 'd'
    je setd
    cmp al, 'f'
    je setf
    cmp al, 'j'
    je setj
    cmp al, 'k'
    je setk
    cmp al, 'l'
    je setl
    cmp al, ';'
    je setcolon
    jmp stopnote    

seta:            ; C4
    mov ax, 4560 
    jmp playnote

sets:            
    mov ax, 4063 ; D4
    jmp playnote

setd:
    mov ax, 3619 ; E4
    jmp playnote

setf:
    mov ax, 3416 ; F4
    jmp playnote

setj:
    mov ax, 3043 ; G4
    jmp playnote

setk:
    mov ax, 2711 ; A4
    jmp playnote

setl:            ; B4
    mov ax, 2415
    jmp playnote

setcolon:        ; C5
    mov ax, 2280
    jmp playnote
    
playnote:
    mov al, 182 ; plays the sound, ax determines the frequency
    out 43h, al
    out 42h, al
    mov al, ah
    out 42h, al
    in al, 61h
    or al, 00000011b
    out 61h, al
    jmp input

stopnote:   ; stops the speaker
    in al, 61h
    and al, 11111100b
    out 61h, al
    jmp input

times 510 - ($-$$) db 0 ; bootsector magic number
dw 0xaa55
```

I'm running this in QEMU. If you want to run this yourself, assemble this using:

```
nasm -fbin code.asm -o code.bin
```

And run the bootsector using:

```
qemu-system-x86-64 code.bin -soundhw pcspk
```

Comment: `mov al, 182` overwrites the low byte of AX.  Pass the frequency in a different register so you can `outb` to port 43h conveniently before copying the low/high half of the frequency to AL for outb to port 42h.